# 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, mariadb, mysql-error-1292

What am I not seeing? I have no idea why I am getting this error. It shouldn't even be asking for an integer.

```
MariaDB [ams]> describe server_current_status;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| serverid | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notify   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totime   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fromtime | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [ams]> UPDATE server_current_status SET notify = 'SOME' AND status = 'DOWN' WHERE serverid = '8';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 2

MariaDB [ams]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'SOME' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'SOME'  |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Figured it out. Forgot comma. There is an "AND" where there should be a comma

Answer (score 3):

```
notify = 'SOME' AND status = 'DOWN'
```

This is a boolean expression. The engine reads it as something like

```
notify = ('SOME' AND (status = 'DOWN'))
```

So the engine tries to convert `'SOME'` to a boolean (which is `0` or `1` in MySQL/MariaDB)

You probably want this:

```
notify = 'SOME', status = 'DOWN'
```